# Regression testing for web services and SharePoint workflows - What should I research?

Tags: automated-testing, tools, regression-testing, test-creation

Apologies if this question has been addressed before or not relevant to this exchange. I did some initial searching and I've only recently discovered this area of stackexchange so I'm unsure of the general 'flow' of things.

My work has tasked me with researching and putting together a loose proposal for an automated regression testing system for our SharePoint environment. This incorporates a number of custom web parts and web services which I believe will make a majority of "out of the box" testing solutions a poor choice.

Essentially I'm wondering what tools I should be researching to test:

- SharePoint web parts are still functioning
- End to end testing of a workflow
- Web Service SOAP calls are still functioning and return the desired result.

To be honest since I graduated I've had very little to do with any sort of automated testing tools. I test my own applications and have written far too many test cases but haven't had to do anything automated to this scale so please keep in mind that a lot of terms are likely to be above my current skill level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: look at [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) for WebService regression tests. There are plenty of tools for web application regression testing, you can try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for example.

Comment: Appreciated - will look into both products